# Hide data label containing series name if value is zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have made a chart in excel in which I would like to hide the data label if value is zero. For data labels that contain the value itself this is done by using custom formating as explained here [How can I hide 0-value data labels in an Excel Chart?](https://superuser.com/questions/654279/how-can-i-hide-0-value-data-labels-in-an-excel-chart).

However this doesn't work if the data label doesn't contain the value itself but the series name. Is there a way to hide the data label containing the series name if the value is zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this falls into the world of VBA.  Working on *individual* data labels is fairly limited otherwise.

Here is code that will iterate through the series in a chart, their data points, and then delete those labels which correspond to a point with `Value=0`.

There is a line of code in there (commented) that will add the data labels again to all of the points to reset them.  If you just want to delete, then you can skip this line.

Edit: added in an outer loop on `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects` in order to process all of the charts on a sheet.

```
Sub RemoveZeroValueDataLabel()

    'runs through every chart on the ActiveSheet
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject

    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set cht = chtObj.Chart

        Dim ser As Series
        For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection

            Dim vals As Variant
            vals = ser.Values

            'include this line if you want to reestablish labels before deleting
            ser.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel, , , , True, False, False, False, False

            'loop through values and delete 0-value labels
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                If vals(i) = 0 Then
                    With ser.Points(i)
                        If .HasDataLabel Then
                            .DataLabel.Delete
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next i
        Next ser
    Next chtObj
End Sub
```

This answer grabs `Values` from the `Series` using the technique [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122329/determining-the-value-of-a-point-in-excel-vba).

Here is the result on some random data where a couple of 0 value bars have had their data labels deleted.

[image: chart with labels deleted]

Comment: Wow Bryon, you're a big help! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: He Bryon, I want to run the above script for every graph in that worksheet. I'm not that experienced with VBA but I implemented the following line in your code:     For Each cht In Sheets("Worksheet").chart like described here http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/8/15/loop-through-all-charts-in-activeworkbook. However this returns an error saying this cant be done with that object. My question is whether the code you proposed can be used in a for loop? And if so how?

Comment: See edit above.  You need to loop through `Worksheet.ChartObjects`.  The `ChartObject` is a container which contains info about the Chart and how it is arranged on a `Worksheet`.  Inside the `ChartObject` is the `Chart` property which gets us back to the same spot as before.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838184.aspx

Comment: Bryon again thanks a lot this works and saved me a lot of time! Not familiar with VBA (yet) but hoping to get better at it in the future so i wont have to ask these questions.

Comment: Fastest way to learn is to record macros and make them better.  You will get a lot better also if you always declare variables: `Dim sht as Worksheet, rng as Range, ... etc.`.  This prompts the Intellisense to list the properties as you go.  It also forces you to know what you are trying to do instead of just grabbing variables and hoping it works out.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a custom formatting code to your labels, which is the same kind of code that is used to format numeric cells (date, percentage, currency, etc.). Custom format code has the following syntax:

```
<positive>[;<negative>[;<zero>[;<nan>]]]
```

You need to copy the existing format code two times (separated by `;`), and then put an extra `;` behind, which would mean an empty string if the value is zero. For example, if your labels are formatted as percentage, you will see the code

```
0%
```

for a currency format the code would be

```
$#,##0
```

Corresponding codes with empty strings for zero values are

```
0%;0%;
$#,##0;$#,##0;
```

respectively.

As a side note, custom formatting codes are often used to apply different colors to positive/negative numbers, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1262919/what-colours-are-available-to-use-with-a-custom-number-format-excel).

Answer (score -1):

You could delete all your 0s (Find and Replace to replace all your 0s with a true blank matching entire cell content, `=""` doesn't work).

[image]

Comment: Hi selwyth, thanks!! This indeed solves the problem. However the source data are formulas which are then replaced. I have to make these graphs every month so I would need to restore these formula's also every month. Since it are around ten different graphs I would like to minimize the amount of manual labour. The VBA code proposed by Bryon will work for this goal. Thanks a lot, another trick I can add to my excel toolbox :)