# What Colours Are Available To Use With a Custom Number Format EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

**NOTE. Not to be confused with Conditional Formatting**

When using the Custom Numbers in Excel I often use `RED` font for a negative number.

See image below.

[image]

What other Colours can be used in this way ?

I know Green & Blue work, but is there a full list available ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In addition to the 8 named colors you can also use [ColorX], where X is a number between 1 and 56. The named colors are identical to [Color1] to [Color8].

A quick way to see all the colors provided is to run the following in the immediate window in VBA (preferably in an empty workbook):

```vb
for x = 1 to 56:cells(x,1) = "AAAA":cells(x,1).numberformat = "[COLOR"&x &"]@":Next x
```

Comment: @Naryb. Yes. It's true. Great answer. I've tested it in Office 2007. Here is the [56 color palette](http://www.excelsupersite.com/what-are-the-56-colorindex-colors-in-excel/)

Comment: Note that the individual colors in the 56-color palette are customizable. @jcb

Comment: Your answer looks misleading.   Based on the [link](http://www.excelsupersite.com/what-are-the-56-colorindex-colors-in-excel/) that [jcbermu provided](https://superuser.com/q/1262919/150988#comment1858905_1262981), you should say, “In addition to the 8 named colors you can also use [ColorX], where X is a number between **9** and 56.” — because Color 1 though Color 8 ***are*** the eight named colors.

Comment: @Scott - I've edited to clarify the overlap, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 18):

According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4), There are only 8 colors, the list is:

```
[Black]

[Green]

[White]

[Blue]

[Magenta]

[Yellow]

[Cyan]

[Red]
```

It applies to  Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2010 and Excel 2007

Comment: I was hoping for a lot more variation than that ! but thanks for the info

Comment: If you want to use other colors, I'm fairly sure most of the Custom Number formatting rules can be emulated using conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If l'm not mistaken Excel has 56 Colour available to use with Number Format. Either use Name or Colour number.

```
[Blue Grey] $#, ##0; [Sea Green]-$#, ##0
[Color4] $#, ##0; [Color3]-$#, ##0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the colors also by using color4 or color44 for orange. Just play with the numbers to get more colors.