# Where can I find the grammar guide for Excel format syntax?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to control the display of Excel cells using the customized format.

For example

```
#,##0;(#,##0)
```

will shows positive numbers as usual, but negative numbers with brackets instead of with a `-` sign.

Where can I find the introduction of the syntax? For example, I don't know how to make negative numbers to show as red. Also, I'm not sure how to specify the precision.

Comment: Check out https://superuser.com/q/1262919/774984 for more info on colours available to use

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this Microsoft article ["Review guidelines for customizing a number format"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5)

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> ```
>    <POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>
> ```
>
> For example, you can use these code sections to create the following custom format:
>
> ```
>    [Blue]#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00);0.00;"sales "@
> ```

Comment: Who felt the need to downvote this? Can you please leave a comment with your reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

You can use these Custom formats to put **Negative Numbers** `in Red color, inside Brackets` with `Minus Sign`, and **Positive Numbers** without `Brackets and any Sign in Black Color`, *(which can be Blue or Even Green also).*

`[Black]#,##0.00_);[Red](-#,##0.00);0.00`

`#,##0.00_);[Red](-#,##0.00)`

*For example:*

[image]

`99,000.00`

[image]

This Custom Format will show **Negative Number with Minus Sing in Black Color without Brackets**.

`#,##0.00_)  -99,000.00`

*For more details you can check these Web Sites:*

https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/

**Note,** Color codes `[Black]` &  `[Red]` are editable and should like, `[Blue]` or `[Green]`.

Comment: Write you concern, Why down voted this post?