# How do I show small negative values on an Excel line chart without changing the Y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

This is the Y-axis format I want

[image]

The problem is that the last few values are very small negative numbers, and the line gets cut off as a result. When I expand the Y axis minimum value (as seen here):

[image]

this prevents the line from being cut off, but changes the Y-axis format, creating a label and gridline at -5, which I do not want. Essentially, I want the graph to go down to Y=-3 or so, but keep the Y-axis labels and gridlines at 0,100,200, etc.

This is the closest I can get:

[image]

If you were to crop the graph just below the X-axis labels, so that there is no -100 value or gridline shown, it would be the graph I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom number format to get rid of the -100 axis label.  This approach comes from an [answer by @JonPeltier](https://superuser.com/questions/654279/how-can-i-hide-0-value-data-labels-in-an-excel-chart/1285585#1285585).

Format the y-axis and under "Number", uncheck the "Linked to Source" box and add a custom format like:

`#,##0;;#,##0`

The format for negative numbers (which would be between the two semicolons) is blank, so negative numbers won't appear.

Getting rid of the gridline is trickier.  I don't think any version of Excel allows you to select just one gridline, to delete or format it.  Any changes apply to all horizontal (or vertical) gridlines.

I think the best you can do is [add a shape](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-shapes-0e492bb4-3f91-43b5-803f-dd0998e0eb89) to your graph to cover the gridline.  This is generally under Insert > Shape... or Insert > Picture > Shape...  After you've added it, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-click the shape and format it with no line, no shadow, no gradient and white fill. Then drag it into place to cover the gridline.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is definitely not a great answer, but maybe it will be good enough to help you...
If you copy a range of cells, such as the green outlined selection in this screenshot,

[image: Original Graph]

And then past as a linked picture...

[image: Paste as Linked Picture]

The pasted image is cropped where the cell boundaries were on the original selection. As you can see in this pic.

[image: Pasted Graph Picture]

There is still a small tail visible on the vertical axis, but you can eliminate most of the excess from your example.