# Hiding 0% in MS Excel Charts (Windows OS)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can you please help me to understand how to hide 0% values in excel charts & at the same time, format the higher values with 1-2 decimals?

For non-percent numbers, I got the solution from another user question [How can I hide 0-value data labels in an Excel Chart?](https://superuser.com/questions/654279/how-can-i-hide-0-value-data-labels-in-an-excel-chart)

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Sk

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether the custom format `#,##0.00%;(#,##0.00%);` is helpful.

[image]